# Show/Hide password toggle in password field in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have edited code of script.js for show/Hide password toggle in password field in Keycloak but It is not working. Please see it and let me know, How can I make it work? Thank you

Addition in **script.js**:

```
// Rudimentary method for adding a password reveal button.
window.onload = function() {
  var fToggle = function($password, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const type = $password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    $password.setAttribute('type', type);
    this.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
  };

  var createReveal = function(passwordId, toggleId) {
    var password = document.getElementById(passwordId);
    if ((password) && (password.style) && (password.style.display !== 'none')){
      var icon = document.createElement("i");
      icon.id = toggleId;
      icon.classList.add('password-reveal', 'bi', 'bi-eye-slash');
      icon.addEventListener('click', fToggle.bind(icon, password)); 
      password.parentNode.insertBefore(icon, password.nextSibling);
    }
  };

  createReveal('password', 'togglePassword');
  createReveal('password-new', 'togglePasswordNew');
  createReveal('password-confirm', 'togglePasswordConfirm');
```

**css**:

```
.password-reveal {
  color: #5500B3;
  margin-left: -40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is import of library of icon is missing. It is working for me as follow:

**In script.js file:**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    var fToggle = function($password, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const type = $password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
      $password.setAttribute('type', type);
      this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    };
  
    var createReveal = function(passwordId, toggleId) {
      var password = document.getElementById(passwordId);
      if ((password) && (password.style) && (password.style.display !== 'none')){
        var icon = document.createElement("i");
        icon.id = toggleId;
        icon.classList.add('password-reveal', 'fa','fa-eye', 'fa-eye-slash');
        icon.addEventListener('click', fToggle.bind(icon, password));
        password.parentNode.insertBefore(icon, password.nextSibling);
      }
    };
  
    createReveal('password', 'togglePassword');
    createReveal('password-new', 'togglePasswordNew');
    createReveal('password-confirm', 'togglePasswordConfirm');
}, 5);
```

**In styles.css**

```
 @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
.password-reveal {
  color: #0052f0;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -40px;
  font-size: 24px !important;
}
```

For edting the files, go inside your **keycloak** project, go to your **theme folder** inside **keycloak folder** and then there will be the **css folder** with file **styles.css** and **js folder** with **script.js**. You can edit the code there.

If these folders or files do not exist then create them and add this code. And then update **theme.properties** file.

For example in the **theme.properties** file, add:

```
styles=css/styles.css
scripts=js/script.js
```

Comment: How to add the script without modifying the template?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski for editing the files, go inside your keycloak project, go to your theme folder inside keycloak folder and then there will be the css folder with file styles.css and js folder with script.js. You can edit the code there without modifying the template

Comment: Hi, in my keycloak I cannot find a js folder. I only got css folder. What should I do?

Comment: @BuwanekaSudheera try to add a new folder with the name js in the resources folder in which you have css folder. And then add a new file in the js folder with name script.js. And add this code there.

Comment: Hi @HSW I tried what you said. But it doesn't work. Do I have to import it into theme.properties file?

Comment: I added scripts=js/script.js this line into theme.properties file and it worked. Thank you so much.